# Relation between Russian "пока" and Czech "zatím"

Tags: etymology, slavic-languages, vocabulary, russian, czech

I have noticed that the Russian word пока means the same as zatím in Czech in both meanings. The first is as a conjunction and the second use means goodbye. I am aware that in Czech the equivalent expression to пока as a conjunction is "zatím co" but I still think this is a very interesting coincidence.

Example of the first use:

- он смотрел телевизор пока она спала
- on se díval na televizi, zatím co ona spala

The second use is a word meaning goodbye.

I also know that Russian has за тем which <s>has the same meaning as Czech zatím</s> but cannot be used as a greeting. (EDIT: This is incorrect, see @Yellow Sky's answer)

So, the question is, how did it come so, that these seemingly unrelated words have the same two uses. I tried looking up both of them in Wiktionary with no success but this is where my etymology skills end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, about some things which are not very true in the question.
The Russian *за тем* means “behind/after that ...” like in *за тем домом* “behind that house”. There is a Russian adverb *[затем](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC)* “then, next” which also has an archaic meaning “because, in order to” as an answer to *зачем?* “why? for what reason/purpose?” and it is this *затем* that has some semantic connection with the Czech *[zatím](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zat%C3%ADm)*, but the meaning and the usage are quite different.

*[Zatímco](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zat%C3%ADmco#Czech) / zatím co* is a conjunction, usually written together with *co*, while *zatím* is an adverb. *Пока* can function as both a conjunction and an adverb.

The reason why both *пока* and *zatím* can mean “goodbye” is quite simple: *пока* means “**so long** as, while” and *zatím co* also means “**so long** as, while”, so it is not very strange that they both mean “so long = goodbye”.

A more interesting question is how and why “so long” came to mean “goodbye”. Online Etymology Dictionary [explains](https://www.etymonline.com/word/so%20long) it by German influence, and Czech had been heavily influenced by German. Still, the meaning of most parting expressions is a wish of well-being or a hope to meet again, so “be well **so long** as we are parted” shortened to “so long” is a connection with “goodbye”.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your detailed answer, sorry for the mistakes in the question, I am a complete beginner in Russian (but a Czech native speaker). The "so long" thing occurred to me a little but I wanted to know if it is really that way. If there is no other game-changing answer within 24h, I will check this as the correct answer.

Comment: *за тем* is like *za tím*, I did not realise that when I was writing the question...